# How to know if a string contains substring with special symbols?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

why this code:

```
p="PS02 - Fretted stereo2stereo (x86)" 
s="PS02 - " 
if string.match(p,s) then 
  reaper.ShowConsoleMsg("Yes!")
end
```

gives us "Yes!"

But this Code:

```
p="PS02 - Fretted stereo2stereo (x86)" 
s="PS02 - F" 
if string.match(p,s) then 
  reaper.ShowConsoleMsg("Yes!")
end
```

gives us nothing??

How to know if some string contain another (with whitespaces or another symbols like "-" or "()")?

Comment: Either replace `string.match(p,s)` with `string.match(p,(s:gsub("%p", "%%%0")))` or replace `if string.match(p,s) then` with `if string.find(p,s,1,true) then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"PS02 - "` <strike>works</strike> appears to work because it's actually matching only the substring `"PS02 "`.  This is because the `-` in `(space)-` means "match (space) zero or more times, but as few times as possible."

Magic characters `^$()%.[]*+-?` must each be prefixed (escaped) with a leading `%`... so the correct patterns in each case above are  `"PS02 %- "` and `"PS02 %- F"`.

Comment: This is going to be tricky for us folks coming from other languages (perl here). Lua patterns are not the regexes we grew up with.